# transistor voltage amplifier question

Tags: voltage, transistors, amplifier

I have this task: When Vb changes, shall Vc change -4 time as much. Can you deside Re so this will happend?

can somebody please help me?

[image]

Comment: What steps have you taken to figure it out for yourself?

Comment: Are you sure you mean "-4 times as much?"

Comment: It will never happen as V1 is 0V. You might want to study a bit more on the common emitter amplifier and then all will be clear.

Comment: English is not my native language, but it is what the task says.. I have not done much, because i dont now where to start. I am looking for an equation to find the value, but so far i havent find any.

Comment: equations are: Ic = Ib * hfe  and:  V=IR

Comment: Unless V1 is a current source, pls put a resistor to the base of the transistor. You need that 0.6V drop across the base and emitter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a  hint.

Imagine V1 is 2 V. The transistor's emitter is 0.7 V lower than the base voltage, so it is at 1.3 V. A current I = 1.3/Re flows. This same current flows through the collector (ignoring beta effects). So the collector voltage is 12 V - I*1k.  Now, if V1 increases to 3 V, the emitter will increase to 2.3 V, and I will increase to I_new = 2.3/Re, and the collector will decrease to 12 - I_new*1k.

The gain is the change in collector voltage divided by the change in emitter voltage.